# Finding size of a character array knowing only its pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

First of all let me make one thing very clear that I'm aware of the following code which uses the fact of encountering of a NULL while incrementing the size.

```
//p is a pointer to a character array aka string
//size is the length of the string
for (char *i = p; *i != '\0'; i++, size++)
        ;
    size--;
```

What I am interested in is this >> [Make your own sizeof() operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-size-of-array-in-cc-without-using-sizeof-operator/)

But the above article only works for an integer array. I came up with a code for a character array as follows

```
//p points to a character array
int size1 = (int)(*(&p + 1) - p);
```

But it does not work. Can someone tweak it a bit forcing it to work or tell me why it is wrong.

Comment: Its impossible.

Comment: What is the type of `p`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 'p' points to the first element of a character array.

Comment: @tkausl Why is it impossible?

Comment: If you want to find the number of elements in an array after passing it to a function, you are out of luck. The array identifier decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in the function call, so the only thing you have in the function is a pointer to a single `char` (or `int` or whatever), and no way of knowing how many `char`s are in the array. The linked code is using a pointer to _the array itself_. A pointer to an array and a pointer to the first element of an array are different things (despite that people often use these terms somewhat interchangeably).

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you so much. Actually not only a function call but even assingment of &arr[0] to a pointer and applying the formula gives an error.

Comment: @ManasSingh -- how did you initialize `p`? Did you do `char *p = "abcd";` or `char p[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };`, or even `char p[] = "abcd";`? The last two make `p` an array, but the first one makes `p` a pointer. Only the last two could hope to work with this method.

Comment: Too much not shown.  Post a [mcve].